# SP Designer 2013 bind parameter to item name

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-designer, xslt-list-view-web-part

Trying to bind a parameter to the name of the item. I've found all kinds of examples of how to bind to the query string:

```
<ParameterBinding Name="myParam" Location="QueryString(ID)" DefaultValue="0"/>
```

But the name of the item isn't in the query string.

I found [this page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff806155(v=office.14).aspx) documenting the other locations of Connection/Postback, Server/Form, Web Part properties, or Control ID, but I don't know how to use any of those.

**Additional information**
Sorry if this was too vague here is a little more detail.

I have a document set edit form. Along the bottom of the form I want to have a list view that shows the documents that are part of the document set. As far as I know the only way to filter those is by using their **parent link** or **FileRef**, which is the path to the item an includes the name of the document set.

If I hand code the CAML query with the name of a specific document set then I get all the documents for that set -- but of course (since it is hard coded) it is the same for every document set.

So I don't really care about binding a parameter, except that it seems to be the most likely way to accomplish what I need.

And my plan was to use SharePoint Designer because I couldn't see any other way to do it.

If there is any other way to show the documents in a document set on the document set edit form, I'm game for that.

Comment: The question is a bit difficult to understand. You would want to bind a parameter to the Title of an item. But where does this Parameter come from, query string? And where your item is seen i.e. New/Display/Edit/View form? Also how you to want to achieve this, through SPD? It would great if you rewrite your question.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I've updated the post with hopefully more clear information. And yes that would be my question "where does this parameter come from." The name isn't in query string, so that is why I'm hoping it can be retrieved in some other manner. It would seem that since any form -- edit, view, etc -- can display the name that it should also be possible to retrieve it for a parameter, right?